# How can I access a inner class in a Parent class from within a Child class?

Tags: java, inheritance

Dears,

I have a Parent and Child class:

```
public class Parent{

    protected class Inner{
    
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent{

    protected class Inner{
    
    }
}
```

And I want to use the Inner Child classes in the parent:

```
myMethod(Inner inner)
```

Is setting the Inner class to protected enough to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your provided code, the two classes named `Inner` are utterly, completely unrelated. You just.. have two classes that so happen to have the same name. It's like `java.awt.List` and `java.util.List`: Yes, same name, but this means nothing at all as far as equivalence (they are as different as guns and grandmas) and access rules (the access rules are what they are; that they share a name has no bearing on it).

To name them 'properly', you can write `Child.Inner` and `Parent.Inner` which differentiates them. Just writing `Inner` will be interpreted by javac as one or the other depending on imports and context (inside the braces that go with `Child extends Parent {}`, it is interpreted as `Child.Inner` due to that being a same-file sibling, unless you have an explicit import; most other places it'll either not compile or be interpreted as `Parent.Inner`). Given that these are somewhat esoteric rules, best bet is to just not write just `Inner` in such a case, and always be explicit. "But shorter code" is a good rule of thumb but rules of thumb are called that because they aren't always right. Otherwise they'd just be called "The rule", no need to involve thumbs.

But, before doing that, why are you have 2 unrelated classes with the same name in the same project in the first place? That's confusing even if everybody writes out a full name to try to avoid confusion.

What is your *actual* intent here?

### I want `Child.Inner` to be a subclass of `Parent.Inner`, mirroring `Child` and `Parent`'s relationship

Then write that:

```
public class Child extends Parent {
  public class Inner extends Parent.Inner {}
}
```

I'd still strongly consider picking different names here. Perhaps `public class ChildInner` - obviously `Inner` is just a placeholder name here and not what's really in your project, so I can't give much advice on what name to pick. Just that 'same name' is a bad idea.

Your `Child.Inner` has a hidden-named instance of `Child` available to it, which is a more specific kind of `Parent`, and it is itself a more specific kind of `Parent.Inner`, meaning **every method** in any of the 4 classes is available to it. If `Parent` or `Child` has a method named `x()` and `Parent.Inner` or `Child.Inner` also has a method named `x()`, you can differentiate using this syntax:

```
Child.this.x();
```

But, again, why would you confuse things like this by using the same name so many times?

### I just want the code in `Child` to be able to access methods and fields from `Parent.Inner`.

Then do *not* make a second class, your intent is clearly not to have 2 inner classes in the first place. Every instance of `Child` is a more specific kind of `Parent`, so you can make new instances of `Parent.Inner` whose 'enclosing instance' is in fact an instance of `Child`, no problem.

In `Child.java`:

```
Inner inner = new Inner();
```

And outside of that:

```
Parent.Inner inner = someInstanceOfChild.new Parent.Inner();
```

Naturally, as the code in Parent's Inner has no idea if the instance of the enclosing class is an instance specifically made with `new Parent()` or an instance of some more specific type, e.g. `new Child()`, no method that exists in only in Child can be invoked, but you can instanceof and cast your outer this instance:

```
if (Parent.this instanceof Child) {
    Child c = (Child) Parent.this;
    c.methodOnlyInChild();
}
```

works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

No,

you need to extend the Inner class in the Child class like this:

```
public class Child extends Parent{

    protected class Inner extends Parent.Inner{
```

That way your myMethod(Inner inner) will recognize the Child classes as children of the Parent.Inner class. Otherwise the Child class's Inner will not be of the type Parent.Inner (and will not be recognized as a subclass of that class (or could be used in the same method)).